# Is there a way to omit a subproject when I am targeting multiple frameworks?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I've inherited a project for a library that targets .NET framework 4.6.1. I'm going away for the weekend and I'd like to do work on my mac laptop using VS Code (which, obviously, means I'd need to target .NET core).

The project is structured into a bunch of sub-projects -- e.g.

```
MyProject/
   MyProject.SubProj1/
   MyProject.SubProj2/
```

Complicating things is the fact that some *pieces* of the subprojects can't be ported to .NET core (they depend on Speech and Windows Forms), but I can extract all the framework-specific bits into a separate subproject (e.g `MyProject.Windows`).

How would I edit the .csproj files to target both frameworks, to be able to build JUST the shared projects that use .net core on my mac (so I can test it) but then all the projects (targeting .net framework) on my PC?

Edit: I only have two classes that have framework dependencies, and I’m totally fine omitting them when I target core. I’m just confused on how to set up the build tasks so that the rest of the project is “shared”.

Comment: all your references for project would still need to target new framework (which is Core), but they are built for .NET Framework, so i don't think it is possible for you. if only you had some libraries built for Standard, then you could copy them and embed into your Core app

Comment: Ah! I am totally fine omitting those classes that have framework dependencies when I compile on my mac. I’m just confused on how to do that! I’ve edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

This would require you to port over the code to .NET Core. You can't just switch the framework and have it magically work. Migrations from .NET Framework to .NET Core usually require heavy lifting and refactoring.

I've migrated tons of apps to core and a lot of the time I had to find new libraries to replace the old ones and rewrite a lot of code.

I don't think you're going to get off easy on this one

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned — I have all the other pieces working in .net core, it’s just two classes that are easy to pull out into their own project (and omit when Im working on my Mac) so it’s more about getting the .csproj files to work so when I target it compiles under .net framework, it compiles all projects, and when I compile under .net core it compiles all of them EXCEPT the project containing the two  classes with framework dependencies.